# Assuming[a ∈ Reals, Conjugate[a]] fails to invoke assumptions

Tags: assumptions

Miminmal working example:

```
Assuming[a ∈ Reals, Conjugate[a]]
```

Returns `Conjugate[a]` instead of `a`. Why doesn't it use the assumptions?

[Edit:] I'm not looking for an alternative function, I am trying to understand why Assuming doesn't affect the evaluation of Conjugate. (I found Refine on my own). The comment by @Szabolcs may be the answer: Conjugate doesn't use Assumptions, it has to be a function that explicitly does simplification. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Because `Assuming` doesn't transform or simplify expressions. It simply provides assumptions to other functions that can do so. Try `Assuming[a \[Element] Reals, Simplify@Conjugate[a]]`. This is equivalent to `Simplify[Conjugate[a], Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals]`

Answer (score 5):

The function that you need to apply assumptions is `Refine`.  I use it quite often, when I don't need or want more complete simplification.

```
Assuming[a ∈ Reals, Refine[Conjugate[a]]]
(* a *)
```